# Cannot find HttpPost method in controller class

Tags: html, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an html form that uses HTTP.Post to talk to a method in the controller class. I don't have a specific view representing this method, just an HttpPost ActionResult without a relative cshtml view class. My code that calls this method is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveCallout", "SaveCallout"))
{  
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ClientId, new SelectList(Model.Clients, "ClientId", "Name"))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @id = "descriptionText" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-large" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="submit" value="Create Callout" />
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="@Url.Action("EmptyThisCallout", "Callout", null)" id="EmptyCart" style="float: left;">Clear Callout</a>
}
```

And my controller method is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveCallout(CalloutViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var Callout = new Callout();
        TryUpdateModel(Callout);
        try
        {
            Callout.ClientId = viewModel.ClientId;

            Callout.CalloutDate = DateTime.Now;
            //Save invoice
            proent.Callouts.Add(Callout);
            proent.SaveChanges();
            //Process the invoice
            var tempCallout = CalloutLogic.GetCallout(this.HttpContext);
            tempCallout.CreateCallout(Callout);

            return RedirectToAction("Complete", new { id = Callout.CalloutId });
        }
        catch
        {
            //Invalid - redisplay with errors
            return View(Callout);
        }
    }
```

This has worked flawlessly in a similar context before, but now I get the error message "The view 'SaveCallout' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations". I understand it is searching for a View but I have never needed one before for this process.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Maybe I need to post more of my code?

Comment: What is the controller class name where `SaveCallout` action is defined?

Comment: Why do you have controller name `SaveCallout` same as post action name? `BeginForm("SaveCallout", "SaveCallout")` I'm just curious.

Comment: SaveCalloutController is the name of the controller class. I'm not sure why I landed up doing that, it made sense at the time and as i said before, it used to work up until i changed something, but i'm not sure what!

Answer (score 1):

The change you made is `return View(Callout);` in `catch`.

`return View(...)` without providing a View name searches for a View that has the same name as your Action. You should put a View at `Views -> SaveCallout -> SaveCallout.cshtml` if it was intentional, but I do not think it is.

I don't know what view you are making that `HttpPost` from. Let it be called `Foo`. If you want to return to `Foo` view again, you should do:

```
catch(...)
{
    return View("Foo", Callout);
}
```